# QML: Fetch mouse event of MouseArea in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to connect `MouseArea` mouse event with C++, But the `QQuickMouseArea` is private, so i could not fetch the signal.

Like this:

```
QObject::connect(mouseAreaObj, SIGNAL(released(QMouseEvent*)),
                 handlerObj, SLOT(handleEvent(QMouseEvent*)));
```

Is there any way to solve this?

And if not able, i wonder why Qt not allow us to access `QQuickMouseArea`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of listening to `QQuickMouseArea` signals, you can get it as a `QObject` and set your `handlerObj`  as an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) of your `mouseAreaObj` like this : `mouseAreaObj->installEventFilter(handlerObj)`.

Then you'll need to implement [`eventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) in your `handlerObj`.
Maybe something like this :

```
bool HandlerObject::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        return handleEvent(static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event));
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made the connection in qml `mouseArea.clicked.connect(cppObject.onClicked)` and then in C++ simply received a `QObject*` which has properties as expected:

```
void CppClass::onClicked(QObject *event) {
    qDebug() << "clicked" << event->property("x").toInt();
}
```